# How to modify LoggingTensorHook formatter?

Tags: tensorflow, hook, formatter

sing standard implementation of the cnn given in https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/layers, during the training results are shown with the tensor hook defined as follows

```
# Set up logging for predictions
  tensors_to_log = {"probabilities": "softmax_tensor"}
  logging_hook = tf.train.LoggingTensorHook(
      tensors=tensors_to_log, 
      every_n_iter=50)
```

In this way the whole tensor values are printed. How can I modify the hook to specify what to print?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass what to print in the tensors dictionary for the hook.

Best,
-Tony

```
last_step = 1000


def formatter_log(tensors):
   """
   Format the log output
   """

   logstring = "Step {} of {}: " \
               " training Dice loss = {:.4f}," \
               " training Dice = {:.4f}".format(tensors["step"],
               last_step,
               tensors["loss"], tensors["dice"])

   return logstring

hooks = [tf.train.StopAtStepHook(last_step=last_step),
        # Prints the loss and step every log_steps steps
        tf.train.LoggingTensorHook(tensors={"step": global_step,
                                   "loss": loss,
                                   "dice": metric_dice},
                                   every_n_iter=log_steps,
                                   formatter=formatter_log)]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks